# R: adding items in a list

Tags: r, list, subset

```
dput(dat)
list(structure(c(0, 0, -1, -2, -1, -2, -1, -2, 0, 2, 99, 0, -1, 
-2, -1, -2), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("type1", "type2"
), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H"))), structure(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 99, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("type1", "type2"), c("A", "B", "C", 
    "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))))

>dat
[[1]]
      A  B  C  D E  F  G  H
type1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 99 -1 -1
type2 0 -2 -2 -2 2  0 -2 -2

[[2]]
      A B C D E  F G H
type1 1 1 1 1 1 99 1 1
type2 2 2 2 2 2  0 3 3
```

Suppose I have the above list with 2 items. Each item consists of a 2x8 `data.frame`. I want to

1) sum up the values for `type1` for each column across the 2 `data.frames` (BUT treat the 99s as a 0)

2) if the `type1` value is 0, keep its corresponding `type2` value. If the `type1` value does not equal 0, set its `type2` value = 0.

3) sum up the values for `type2` for each column across the `data.frames`

4) count the number of `type1` values that are = 0 for each column and sum them up (this is the type1_0 row)

The result should look like this

```
            A B C D E F G H
    type1   1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0     
    type2   0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
  type1_0   1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: Btw, those are matrices, not data frames.

Comment: How did you get 'A' for type1 to be 0.  Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: @akrun thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Stedy I think my main problem is dealing with the matrices within a list. Algorithmically I think I can probably handle steps 1-4,(`if(type1 == 0){type2 = type2} else type2 = 0`, colsum the `type2`, `ind = which(type1 == 99); type1[ind] = 0`, colsum the `type1`.) Something along those lines

Comment: I didn't understand the last type1_0 row, Is it the same as type1 row.  Perhaps `Reduce("+",lapply(dat, function(x) {x[2,][x[1,]!=0] <- 0; replace(x, which(x==99), 0)}))`

Comment: type1_0 row is the number of type1 values that are 0. So in `dat[[1]]`, column A's type1 = 0, in `dat[[2]]' column A's type1 does NOT = 0, so the number of type1 values that are 0 for column A is = 1.

Comment: @akrun thanks. I think your suggestion works great

Comment: Okay, got it.  I think it was the example that caused the trouble.  Checked it with some different value and it worked

Comment: All these steps are incremental, right? I mean to say, the value of `type1` changes after step 1 so do you want this new value of `type1` to be considered for step 2 or still have to consider from what was original (dat) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop through the `list` (`lapply(dat,..`), change the second row ('type2') to 0 for all 'type1' that are not 0, `replace` the 99 with 0, and sum the corresponding elements with `Reduce`.  We extract the 'type1' row i.e. 1st row with `lapply`, `rbind`, convert to logical matrix (`!` - returns TRUE for 0 and FALSE for other values), get the `colSums` and `rbind` with 'res1'.

```
res1 <- Reduce("+",lapply(dat, function(x) {
              x[2,][x[1,]!=0] <- 0
              replace(x, which(x==99), 0)}))


res2 <- rbind(res1, type1_0= colSums(!do.call(rbind, lapply(dat, `[`, 1,))))


res2
#        A B C D E F G H
#type1   1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
#type2   0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
#type1_0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```